# what is meaning of `*(unsigned int*)((unsigned int)block + n*i)`

Tags: c++

```
void* block = ::operator new(n*size);
int i;
for(i = 0;i<BLOCK_SIZE -1;i++){
    *(unsigned int*)((unsigned int)block + n*i) = (unsigned int)block + n*(1+i);
}
*(unsigned int*)((unsigned int)block + n*i) = 0;
```

Question> I am not able to understand the meaning of above code. It seems that one block of memory is pointing to the next block memory.

Can someone please explain it to me?

Comment: You cannot preform arithmetic operations on `void*`. The original programmer cast everything to `unsigned int` to allow arithmetic and then cast it back to pointers. Note that [`std::uintptr_t`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/integer) is the correct integer type for storing a pointer.

Comment: Also note that this is undefined behaviour in Standard C++  ; for it to be compliant the allocation could be `void *block = new unsigned int[n]`, assuming `size == sizeof(unsigned int)`

Comment: @q0987 Is this part of some public / open source code?

Comment: @DanielJour yes. you are right.

Answer (score 0):

```
block[0] = &block[1]
block[1] = &block[2]
block[2] = &block[3]
.
.
.
block[n] = 0  // dereferenced so not NULL, assigned zero as a value
```

AFAIS, it points to next element from beginning to end. Even though the above demonstration seems so simple, it is the logic behind of the code.

Comment: Rather a crude attempt to do `block[i] = &(block[i+1])`. (Note that in the OP's code the right hand operand of that `=` is not dereferenced)

Answer (score 0):

You've gotten it pretty much correct--it's allocating a block of memory, then treating it as a number of nodes, and linking them together as  linked list.

As it stands right now, it looks fairly pointless, since it doesn't allocate any memory to hold data along with the links between the nodes (well, maybe it does--perhaps `n` is actually greater than `sizeof(unsigned *)` and `size` is larger than `BLOCK_SIZE`, so it can accommodate larger items).

If I was going to do something like this, I'd probably write code more like this:

```
unsigned *block = (unsigned *)::operator new(n*size);

for (size_t i=0; i<size-2; i++)
    block[i] = &block[i+1];
block[size-1] = nullptr;
```

Of course, lacking a reason to do that, it's pretty questionable as well--most code would probably be fine with something like:

```
std::vector<unsigned *> block(size);
for (int i=0; i<size-2; i++)
    block[i] = &block[i+1];
block[size-1] = 0;
```

Comment: Q> Why should we cast to `unsigned*` instead of `char*`?